# Как изменить стили элементам если форма не прошла валидацию?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как изменить стили элементам если форма не прошла валидацию?

Comment: `.toggleClass()`, `.addClass()` или `.css()` вам в помощь. :)

Comment: ну наверное в скрипте валидации применять к непршедшим валидацию полям стили тем или иным способом

Comment: добавьте код формы и скрипт вашей валидации